# Access parent properties in child using $this

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to create a simple MVC my personal use and I could really use an answer to this simple question

```
class theParent extends grandParent{

    protected $hello = "Hello World";

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function route_to($where) {
        call_user_func(array("Child", $where), $this);
    }
}

class Child extends theParent {

    public function  __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index($var) {
        echo $this->hello;
    }

}

$x = new theParent();
$x->route_to('index');
```

Now `Child::index()` this throws a fatal error: `Using $this when not in object context` but if I were to use echo `$var->hello`, it works just fine.

I know I can use `$var` to access all properties in the parent, but I would rather use `$this`.

Comment: Where was/is that `Child::index()` that throws the error? I can not see it from the code you posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have an instance of `Child` to call a non-static method upon when you're doing `$x->route_to('index');`  The way you're calling the method, without having made an instance first, is implied static.

There are two ways to correct it.  Either make the `Child` class's methods static:

```
class Child extends theParent {

    public function  __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    static public function index($var) {
        echo self::$hello;
    }

}
```

...or make an instance of the child class for the parent to use:

```
   class theParent extends grandParent{

        protected $hello = "Hello World";
        private $child = false

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function route_to($where) {
            if ($this->child == false)
              $this->child = new Child();
            call_user_func(array($this->child, $where), $this);
        }
    }
```

Of course, both of these samples are rather generic and useless, but you see the concept at hand.

Answer (score 6):

By writing `call_user_func(array("Child", $where), $this)` you are calling the method statically. But as your method isn't static you need some kind of object instance:

```
call_user_func(array(new Child, $where), $this);
```

[Documentation on callback functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php).

Comment: Thanks I like this. Can I create a new instance of this class using a variable? Such that $var = "Child"; and then call_user_func(array(new ${$var}, $where), $this); or something like this? Last time I tried, you couldnt assign objects to string

Comment: Your syntax is nearly right, but you need to use just `new $var` instead of `new ${$var}`. (The latter has a different meaning, it would instantiate the class using a variable variable.)

Answer (score 1):

`$this` gives you access to everything visible/accessible in the current object. That can either be in the class itself (this) or any of it's parents public or protected members/functions.

In case the current class overrides something of a parent class, you can access the parent method explicitly using the `parent` keyword/label, whereas you add `::` to it regardless if it is not a static method.

Protected variables exist only once, so you can not use `parent` to access them.

Is this info of use?